# Blend for Visual Studio2015

Tags: wpf, blend

I am newer to Visual Studio blend. I want to learn the blend for Visual Studio 2015. I have surfed a lot, but i dint find any particular tutorial in this version. Please suggest me some sites and books to learn this

Comment: search google with keywords blend+visual+studio+guide

Comment: also available in youtube as tutorials

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to blend as well, I'm doing through this list, and it seems pretty decent for learning the basics

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBDF977B2F1DAB358

Check it out!